# How do the Explainer, Refiner and Illuminator Badges work?

Tags: discussion

Having just read the blog post on [editing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/?cb=1) I am slightly confused.  Does this simply mean that one has to answer a question and then edit said answer?  Or can a user simply edit and answer two different questions?

If they have to be the same answer, would it make more sense to write "Answered and Edited 1 question", rather than "Edited and Answered 1 question".

Comment: You post an answer **and** you take the time to edit the question you answered within a 12 hour period.  Your answer also must get a score > 0.

Comment: "Answered and Edited 1 question" and "Edited and Answered 1 question" mean the same thing.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Well, to edit a question you have to answer it.  Thus, wouldn't it  be more logical to place the answer first?  Unless you have a way of editing a non-existent answer, which would be equally cool.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert No, you can easily answer first, then edit the question. I've done that many times.  You don't have to edit the question to answer it.  This is just an incentive for people to improve the quality of the questions by editing them.

Comment: @bluefeet Ah, I've just realised how much of an idiot I was.  I meant editing an answer before answering it.  I'm very tired.  Sorry.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert No worries, now go to sleep or get some coffee. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Although the possible solution to the problem is a duplicate, I believe the first part (about what it means) is not.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert: have you read all answers there? My answer there contains the *exact same quote* that Shog gave here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, sorry, my bad Martijn.

Comment: ah ! i thought that meant i have to edit and answer 500 questions in 12 hours :) one question every 86.4 seconds... go!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[I explain the gritty details here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator/240302#240302):

> Final requirements:
>
> Edited *n* questions within 12 hours of posting an answer (that's 12 hours before *or* after answering), where:
>
> - The question was asked by someone other than the answerer
> - Neither the questions nor the answers are deleted
> - The questions are not closed
> - The answers score > 0
> - The question edits changed either body, titles, or both
>
> If *n* >= 1, [an Explainer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/246/explainer) (bronze) is awarded.
>
> If *n* >= 50, [a Refiner badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/247/refiner) (silver) is awarded.
>
> If *n* >= 500, [an Illuminator badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/248/illuminator) (gold) is awarded.
>
> Each badge can be awarded only once per person, per site.
>
> If you're interested in the implementation, [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229333/badge-qualifying-answersedits?threshold=50) is roughly what's being run.

tl;dr: answer a question, then edit *the question*. Or edit the question and then answer it. If your answer then gets voted > 0, it'll count toward a badge.

Comment: For the Illuminator badge, is it necessary that the answer be accepted? I ask because I edit almost every question I answer, yet the count towards Illuminator does not appear to reflect that activity. Rather, it seems to match the rate of accepts, which is fairly low on the tags I answer on.

Comment: Nope, @Mogsdad. The answer *does* have to score 1 or more though, which may be as much of a problem in some tags (however, there's no time constraint on this part; if someone else *ever* finds a given answer useful, it'll count)

Comment: That appears to be it! So it's not enough to _post_ an answer... the description(s) could be updated for clarity. Cheers!

Comment: Excellent answer! For years I thought this means we have to edit & anwer 500 questions within 12 hours, meaning 1.4minutes per answer :)

Comment: @Sliq me too. And I was stunned when I found out that many people have actually earned that crazy badge

Comment: does adding a tag is counted for editing?

Comment: Nope, @kelalaka - only title/body

Comment: So, I guess that if you edit the question the 1st of a month, the guy accepts your answer 4 days later but you edit his question again within 12 hours, it still counts ?

Comment: See my reply to Mogsdad above, @kissu - accept is irrelevant to this.