# Do I understand the Illuminator badge correctly?

Tags: support, badges

The [Illuminator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/105/illuminator) badge is on my list of upcoming ones. I'm reading the description and do the math. It doesn't add up.

Assume infinitely many question asked that I have competence to answer. Assume mean reading time to 30 seconds, mean editing time to 30 seconds and mean time to answer of 60 seconds. To get the badge I'd need to continuously shoot 2 minutes' work 500 times, i.e. 1000 minutes, which is more than 720 minutes (12 hours timespan).

And that's assuming abundance of questions, correct and attentive upvotes, **very** limited time invested into each question etc.

My conclusion is that I'm missing something. I've googled meta for it but must be missing the point. There are explanations and discussions but I simply can't see where I'm stepping wrong. Help, please.

Comment: [What's the refiner badge all about?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272533/whats-the-refiner-badge-all-about) or [How do the Explainer, Refiner and Illuminator Badges work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273074/how-do-the-explainer-refiner-and-illuminator-badges-work)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it means you edit / answer within 12h. 500 Times.

So 12 hours mean the timespan between one edit and answer not that you have to do all of them in 12h. (that would be quite a lot)

Comment: Wphewhwpeh, I thought someone actually attempted that.