# Edit & answered within 12 hours, but I didn't get the Explainer badge

Tags: support, badges

I edited [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239379/visual-studio-tab-header-color-in-the-ide) and answered the same question and have a score > 0. I read that I should get an Explainer badge, but I haven't received it. How come?

Comment: Your edit was only approved 18 minutes ago, badges aren't awarded instantly.

Comment: By the way, does someone know of good canonical for these type of questions?

Comment: There's a canonical [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions), but we can't make cross-site duplicates.

Comment: I've edited the post, the bronze version is called *Explainer*.

Comment: @Gimby Broze badge is for 1 question.

Comment: Yes. Its explainer.

Comment: @Stijn: How about [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273074/2675154)?

Comment: @honk I was looking for a more general "how do badges work" post, but a quick search only yielded posts on MSE. Found a suitable one now, though.

Comment: I could see the badge count incremented to +1. But still the page shows that Explainer badge is yet to achieve.

Comment: [Blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: yeah. storing for the future use to earn again. haha.