# Explainer badge not working correctly

Tags: support, badges

Somehow answering [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497943/java-for-loop-is-not-waiting-for-the-input/47498032#47498032) on Nov. 26 and editing it on Nov. 26 gives me the explainer badge, even though I got an up-vote a few hours ago. I don't see how this would give me this badge since it was answered a while ago, and only just got an up-vote.
[How do the Explainer, Refiner, and Illuminator badges work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273074/how-do-the-explainer-refiner-and-illuminator-badges-work)'s answer implies that the up-vote has to be within the 12 hour period as well, which is why I think this isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's working as intended. The description of the badge says:

> Edit and answer 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0).

The vote can be at any time; what matters is that the editing and answering were within 12 hours.

We also have a [list of badges and their full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/168333) on Meta Stack Exchange. Although that list does not point out that the time of the upvote is irrelevant.

In the post that you linked, the answer says:

> Edited n questions within 12 hours of posting an answer (that's 12 hours before or after answering), where: (...)

The conditions that follow are *not* specified as having to be within 12 hours. Only the editing and the posting of an answer. I'll grant that this is easy to misinterpret.

Congratulations on getting the badge!